# Provider not found exception when creating a FileSystem for my zip?

Tags: java, nio, jimfs

I have created a Zip file on a JimFS `FileSystem` instance. I would now like to read the Zip using the Java `FileSystem` API.

Here is how I create the `FileSystem`:

```
final FileSystem zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(
    source, // source is a Path tied to my JimFS FileSystem
    null);
```

However, this throws an error:

> java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found

Interestingly, the code works with the default `FileSystem`.

- What does this error mean?
- How should I create my Zip `FileSystem`?

Comment: Does `source` have the format described in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)?

Comment: @VGR `source` is just a `Path` (e.g. `/Library/Caches/example.zip`)

Comment: Does `FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("jar", source.toUri().toString(), null), null)` work?

Comment: That gives a `FileSystemAlreadyExistsException`

Comment: How about `FileSystems.getFileSystem(new URI("jar", source.toUri().toString(), null))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported before JDK 12 via that specific constructor (`Path, ClassLoader`)

This was fixed in JDK12, with commit [196c20c0d14d99cc08fae64a74c802b061231a41](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk/commit/196c20c0d14d99cc08fae64a74c802b061231a41)

The offending code was in ZipFileSystemProvider in JDK 11 and earlier:

```java
        if (path.getFileSystem() != FileSystems.getDefault()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
```

Comment: Amazing that they fixed it, and good find!

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it seems hacky and crucially I'm not sure *why* it works.

```
public static FileSystem fileSystemForZip(final Path pathToZip) {
    Objects.requireNotNull(pathToZip, "pathToZip is null");
    try {
        return FileSystems.getFileSystem(pathToZipFile.toUri());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            return FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + pathToZipFile.toUri()));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            return FileSystems.newFileSystem(
                URI.create("jar:" + pathToZipFile.toUri()), 
                new HashMap<>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it's very strange that `ZipFileSystemProvider.getScheme()` returns "jar", not the "zip"

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `source` path points to the zip archive file.

In my case it pointed to the ordinary text file which even had other than '.zip' extension.